# ipv6 support enable on the galaxy tab

Tags: android, android-ndk, ipv6

Currently I am using cCURL client application(which is cross compiled using ndk-build) in my android  device  . Currently my device is getting IPV4 address  .
Now I want to enable the IPV6 support on my device . How to enable ipv6 on my device so that my curl client will use this ipv6 ip ..?

my device details :
samsung galaxy tab 10.1
android os : Honey comb , 3.1

Comment: Hardly a programming question; belongs to Android SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Ice Cream Sandwich 4.0.1 supports ipv6 directly.

For earlier versions, you might have luck with GogoDroid:

- https://code.google.com/p/gogodroid/
- http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1276727